# The argument type 'Future<void> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Two days ago, I tried to find a solution to this problem, but I did not find anything.

```
  Future<void> onBackPressed() {
    return SystemNavigator.pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onBackPressed, // Here I get the error
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
```

I get the error: `The argument type 'Future<void> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()?'`

When I change to `Future<bool>` I get the error: `A value of type 'Future<void>' can't be returned from the method 'onBackPressed' because it has a return type of 'Future<bool>'`.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `onWillPop` configuration of `WillPopScope` requires a function with return type `Future<bool>`, and depending on the return value the pop will be either executed or not, [see here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html):

> If the callback returns a Future that resolves to false, the enclosing route will not be popped.

Since `SystemNavigator.pop()` has a return type of `Future<void>`, you can't return this from your `onBackPressed` function.

You can do this, but I think it will cause a double pop:

```
Future<bool> onBackPressed() async {
  await SystemNavigator.pop();
  return Future.value(true);
}
```

You should use the `onWillPop` method to decide whether the pop which was initiated by the user or your code should be executed or not. A typical example is if you want't to disable pressing back button at the home route which on Android would result in quitting your app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, you could try the following

```dart
Future<true> onBackPressed() {
    systemNavigator.pop();
    return true
  }
```

But I would check why a bool is requested and then provide the logic to return true or false

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pop the view, then let WillPopScope do the job.
The following might just work fine:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => Future.value(true),
          child: Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
```